# Multiple anonymous users can't access .NET web app simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web

I have a .NET a web app that i built for files processing .I am using IIS 7 anonymous user authentication , i also did not require the users to log in, so pretty much any user who has access to the intranet can access the web app.
The users said when two of them try to run their files on app at the same time they receive an error( did not specify it).

My question is :

If i use anonymous authentication is it by default every user will have his\her own session while accessing the app?

Comment: It will be a good idea to ask your users to specify the error as it will help in solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default every user will have their own session. And anonymous authentication is the default scheme for the web. It is unlikely that any web server, by default, would only allow 1 anonymous user at a time.

Most likely, if your app is doing file processing, you may be dealing with file locks and not an issue with IIS. You want to make sure that your code is written so that, if two or more people access it simultaneously, they can not request to same file. Also, you need to make sure that you are properly closing any file streams you open, even in the case of exceptions. Without seeing the code in question, it would be difficult to impossible to give more specific guidance, but hopefully this will help point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks, Goblyn27 , this exactly what i was thinking. i have a file on the server that will be used with other user uploaded files and that file may what causing access issues.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Elmah](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs) to get error report of ypur app!